# Any applications of kinetic physics on cosmological scales?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, cosmology, turbulence

On galaxy cluster scales, one is usually forced to use approximate theories such as [hydrodynamic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_dynamics)s or [magnetohydrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetohydrodynamics) for modelling cosmological phenomena. I wanted to ask if [kinetic theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.2899) is important on galaxy cluster scales (or larger). Smaller scale kinetic events (e.g. [magnetic reconnection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_reconnection), origin of [accretion jets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophysical_jet)) which grow into larger scale events are excluded from this question.

An example of this type of event would be e.g. [turbulence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbulence) on galaxy cluster scales or any other system which would require one to solve the full [Vlasov](http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March02/Bertschinger/Bert3_2.html) or Boltzmann ([link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540257705), chapter 3.2) equation.

Comment: Normally one sees [$n$-body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_simulation) simulations for cosmology, though HD & MHD models can be found.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I believe at least Enzo solves both HD and MHD.

Comment: Enzo does do (M)HD, but Gadget & Vine do n-body/SPH and Ramses does both fluid & n-body.

Comment: This question (v2) seems like a list question.

Comment: I am working with a group of astronomers trying to explain some synchrotron radiation they see in the mergers of galaxy clusters.  The problem is that MHD and MHD turbulence does not seem to be able to explain the emissions, so they are starting to consider alternatives like introducing kappa velocity distribution functions and kinetic-scale wave-particle interactions.

Comment: @honeste_vivere That seems really interesting. I recently read an article on mapping magnetic fields in clusters: http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v6/n7/full/nphys1657.html


Results seem very interesting; they used MHD. By wave-particle interactions do you mean quasilinear theory?

Comment: @honeste_vivere : And feel free to post this as an answer :)

Comment: This is a bit of a pedantic comment, but cosmological scales are typically understood as larger than galactic scales. Cosmological scales are typically $\gtrsim 10\  {\rm Mpc}$ (larger than individual galaxy clusters), whereas galactic scales (size of an individual galaxy) are somewhere around $1-100\ \rm{kpc}$. So by way of clarifying, what scales are you most interested in?

Comment: Galaxy cluster scales :) Thanks for the comment Andrew, I fixed it.